# Problems executing an osascript command via cron

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, reminders, cron

I have a little shell script which creates a new reminder for a project. This works pretty fine and I can execute in the command line `newCfSamples "my new sample"` and the reminder gets created.

I now have a little R script, which figures out what samples are new and it should create a reminder for this. This script works fine as well and creates the Reminders.

Both together, so cron is starting my R script fails at the point when it is executing my little `newCfSamples` script with the following error message: `execution error: Reminders got an error: An error of type -1743 has occurred. (-1743)`.

I then started my script directly with `cron` and this also fails. Here is the complete error message.

```
Subject: Cron <madejung@madejung-2> /Users/madejung/bin/newCfSamples test
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=madejung>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=madejung>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/madejung>
Date: Wed, 14 Sep 2016 15:42:00 +0200 (CEST)

290:540: execution error: Reminders got an error: An error of type -1743 has occurred. (-1743)
```

Would be great if somebody would help me get this running.

My `newCfSamples` script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                               
# Make a new reminder via terminal script                                                                                         
# args: remind <title> <date> <time>                                                                                                                                                                                 
my_date=`date "+%d/%m/%Y"`
my_time='09:00'
osascript - "$1" "${my_date}" "${my_time}" <<END                                                                                                        
on run argv                                                                                                                       
    set stringedAll to date (item 2 of argv & " " & item 3 of argv)                                                               
    tell application "Reminders"                                                                                                  
        make new reminder in list "CF User Sample" with properties {name:item 1 of argv, due date:stringedAll}                                             
    end tell                                                                                                                      
end run                                                                                                                           
END
```

Comment: Since I don't do `R`, I can't really reproduce your environment to test however I did run the _script_ you posted, changing the `list` _item_ to an appropriate target, and it ran fine from Terminal and using `launchd` with the _script_ set as a Launch Agent. (I don't use `cron` anymore as it's depreciated in OS X.) This is with the system logged in and not locked. BTW, What's will all the totally unnecessary white-space in your script? I'm talking about all the trailing space after 10 of the 13 lines of code as shown in [this image](http://imgur.com/7nFSLMD).

Comment: Actually, I just started using the `osascript` and copy and pasted the lines from a online source. I got some strange error messages like `567:570: syntax error: Expected end of line, etc. but found command name. (-2741)` so I thought the white space is correct :-) @user3439894 could you maybe provide your solution? I also tested it with `launchd` and the GUI `LaunchControl` but this also doesn't create the ToDo entries. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3439894 maybe one more thing, when I executed my shell script, there was always a popup message asking for allowance to change `Reminders`. Also when I start using this within my R script. Maybe this is missing in the `Launchd` way? But it didn't asked me?

Comment: Is there a way to always allow R to access Reminders? Today I got asked again. I am wondering if I will overlook this again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. As I mentioned in the above comments, I am using the GUI [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/), I started the job once by hand with the menu Job -> Start and I got a little popup if R is allowed to access Reminders. I clicked yes and now it is working.

It looks like, this popup couldn't be displayed so I could never allow it.

[image: This is how the LaunchControl entry looks like]

Comment: Worth noting [LaunchControl](https://sites.fastspring.com/somazone/product/shop?source=soma-zone) is **not** free and open source. It costs 15 USD https://sites.fastspring.com/somazone/product/shop?source=soma-zone